# Flask app not running on localhost, no error

Tags: python, flask

Similar code to this was working fine, then suddenly not and I have no idea why. Hoping somebody can help. I have the following:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hi"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run that, the output is the following:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

There is no error, but also no "Running on http://localhost:5000/" and nothing loads at that URL ("This site can't be reached") etc.
I have tried specifying the host many ways and many other things. Still get the same. Previously it was working fine, said "Running on http://localhost:5000/," was loading fine in my browser, etc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's your system? try to search a command to kill process related to the 5000 port and try to run your application again

Comment: It wouldn't bind if something were already listening on the same port.

Comment: try specifying a port and see if it works in the new port. Eg: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5050')`. This should open up on http://0.0.0.0:5050. Also make sure you are actually accessing this URL from within your local network.

Comment: What is the exact command you use to run the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the host and the port on your script:

```py
# ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True) # or setting host to '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: hi @pazitos, I had the same issues with the host, I try to use your solution, but it's not working

Comment: I posted this question long ago and forgot all about it. Thank you for all the responses. As best I can recall, and as @dukkee and msanford allude to, my problem was the previous process somehow got orphaned on that port. I found it, killed it, and was good to go. Thanks!